# How to create a new copy of an existing excel sheet(table) within an Excel File using nothing but OLEDB C# SSIS

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, oledb

I am trying to create a copy of an excel template that already currently exist in the excel document that is being worked on and inserted data into. The code is designed to take data from a table, insert it into specific cells of the Excel file, that have named highlighted columns above them so it is formated. I  am using an SSIS script task to iterate through each row of data in the table. Once the data is inserted I am trying to create a copy of the template for the next row of data to be inserted.

```
//Foreach record set of data in table
//Insert data into the template into the specific cells
//Create new sheet for next iteration of data to be inserted
//end script
```

I can ONLY use System.Data.OleDb methods/library because the UAT and PROD servers can not accept additional libraries at this time. So the algorithm is setup like this. The Script is in a Foreach loop, so...

I expect it to create a copy of the current excel sheet it is inserting data into.

```
using (OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(ExcelLocationConnectionString))
{

    ExcelConnection.Open();
    DataTableCollection TablesInFile = ExcelConnection.GetSchema("Tables").DataSet.Tables;

    using (OleDbCommand InsertDataCommand = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        InsertDataCommand.Connection = ExcelConnection;
        DataTable TableToInsertDataInto = TablesInFile[TablesInFile.Count];//Index could be out of range

        if (YestAccountBranch == TodayAccountBranch)           
            AccountBranchChange = "No changes have been made to Account Branch.";
        
        if (YestAccountType == TodayAccountType)           
            AccountTypeChange = "No changes have been made to Account Type.";
        
        if (YestCostCenter == TodayCostCenter)            
            CostCenterChange = "No changes have been made to Cost Center.";
        
        InsertDataSQL = "INSERT INTO [" + TableToInsertDataInto.ToString() + "$B5:F5:I5:L5:P5:T5:Y5:F2] VALUES('" + AccountNumber + "','" +
                    "" + CostCenterChange + "','" + AccountTypeChange + "','" + AccountBranchChange + "','" + TransactionLimit +
                    "','"+ DailyCumulativeLimit +"','" + BLCompanyID + "/" + ClientName + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString() + "')";

        InsertDataCommand.CommandText = InsertDataSQL;
        InsertDataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }

    //Create table in excel sheet
    using (OleDbCommand CreateTableCommand = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        CreateTableCommand.Connection = ExcelConnection;

        string tableName = "AccountChange" + TablesInFile.Count.ToString() + 1;
        CreateTableCommand.CommandText = $"CREATE TABLE [{tableName}]";

    }
        
}
```

Comment: Replacing an old question wholesale with another is no guarantee of a better reception, and often leads to the opposite outcome: a community backlash over what can be seen as an attempt to bypass the normal question lifecycle. Plus, you run the real risk of making the new post off topic, your attempts here were not an improvement, I’m afraid. I’ve locked the post to stop the constant rollback war going on here.

Comment: Note that moderators have continually had to clean up comments here that fell entirely on the wrong side of our [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Please keep in mind that we require everyone to act in a civil manner.